# Stan code chunk not visible in HTML output

Tags: r-markdown, stan, rstan

In an R notebook (using the `html_notebook` output type), the "Preview" button produces a `.nb.html` file in which Stan code chunks fail to appear. Anyone know why? Is this a bug?

**Clarification:** The Stan code chunk runs just fine. The output is available to future code chunks. But in the rendered HTML file, the Stan code is not visible.

Here is a full markdown document as a reproducible example.

````
---
title: "Stan chunk reprex"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(rstan)
```

```{r}
N <- 18
y <- c(rep(1, 12), rep(0, 6))
stan_data <- list(N = N, y = y)
```

```{stan, output.var = "bin_unif"}
data {
    int<lower = 0> N;
    int<lower = 0, upper = 1> y[N];
}
parameters {
    real<lower = 0, upper = 1> theta;
}
model {
    theta ~ uniform(0, 1);  // prior
    y ~ bernoulli(theta);   // likelihood
}
```

```{r}
fit_bin_unif <- sampling(bin_unif, data = stan_data)
fit_bin_unif
```
````

Comment: I think preview does not execute the Stan code. You have to knit it to HTML for that.

Comment: @BenGoodrich "Preview" does not execute any code for any kind of code chunk. I run all the code chunks first, including the Stan chunk. The issue is that, unlike all other code chunks, the Stan chunk is not visible in the HTML output. I suspect it's an RStudio issue.